# unable to form structure and update flag value when it matches from obj

Tags: javascript

unable to form structure as expectedoutput and need to update the flag to true,when name value from items matches to name from obj and update to false when it doesn't matches

```js
let items = [{mnemonic:'first',name:'alm',flag:false},
             {mnemonic:'second',name:'old',flag: false},
             {mnemonic:'first',name:'newValue',flag: false},
             {mnemonic:'second',name:'newValue',flag: false}]

let obj = {
  mnemonic: 'first',
  name: 'newValue'
};

let expectedOutput = [{mnemonic:'first',name:'alm',flag:false},
             {mnemonic:'second',name:'old',flag: false},
             {mnemonic:'first',name:'newValue',flag: true},
             {mnemonic:'second',name:'newValue',flag: true}]


let newArr = items.map(i=> ({
  ...i,
  ...({flag:!items.some(_v=>_v.name == obj.name)?true:false})
}))
  
  console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: `flag: !items.some(_v=>_v.name == obj.name) ? true : false`

Comment: Your `items` and `expectedOutput` is same?

Comment: no, updated the expected output and it should not modify the original items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just match the current item's (in your case it is `i`) to the obj.name and update the flag value accordingly. And it will not update your original items.

Just do the following,

```js
let items = [{mnemonic:'first',name:'alm',flag:false},
             {mnemonic:'second',name:'old',flag: false},
             {mnemonic:'first',name:'newValue',flag: false},
             {mnemonic:'second',name:'newValue',flag: false}]

let obj = {
  mnemonic: 'first',
  name: 'newValue'
};

let expectedOutput = [{mnemonic:'first',name:'alm',flag:false},
             {mnemonic:'second',name:'old',flag: false},
             {mnemonic:'first',name:'newValue',flag: true},
             {mnemonic:'second',name:'newValue',flag: true}]


let newArr = items.map(i=> ({
  ...i,
  ...({flag:i.name === obj.name})
}))
  
  console.log(newArr)
  console.log('Original Items: ', items);
```